# missing \begin{document} error

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, bibliographies

I'm getting a missing `\begin{document}` error despite having a `\begin{document}` in my code.

Other files here (https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B4GteP8rSaosSGZDLTJrbFJlUWs?usp=sharing). It appears the bibliography causes problems.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\newboolean{PrintVersion}
\setboolean{PrintVersion}{false} 
% CHANGE THIS VALUE TO "true" as necessary, to improve printed results for hard copies
% by overriding some options of the hyperref package below.

%\usepackage{nomencl} % For a nomenclature (optional; available from ctan.org)
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amstext} % Lots of math symbols and environments
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx} % For including graphics N.B. pdftex graphics driver 

\usepackage[pdftex,letterpaper=true,pagebackref=false]{hyperref} % with basic options
        % N.B. pagebackref=true provides links back from the References to the body text. This can cause trouble for printing.
\hypersetup{
    plainpages=false,       % needed if Roman numbers in frontpages
    pdfpagelabels=true,     % adds page number as label in Acrobat's page count
    bookmarks=true,         % show bookmarks bar?
    unicode=false,          % non-Latin characters in Acrobat’s bookmarks
    pdftoolbar=true,        % show Acrobat’s toolbar?
    pdfmenubar=true,        % show Acrobat’s menu?
    pdffitwindow=false,     % window fit to page when opened
    pdfstartview={FitH},    % fits the width of the page to the window
    pdftitle={uWaterloo\ LaTeX\ Thesis\ Template},    % title: CHANGE THIS TEXT!
    pdfnewwindow=true,      % links in new window
    colorlinks=true,        % false: boxed links; true: colored links
    linkcolor=blue,         % color of internal links
    citecolor=green,        % color of links to bibliography
    filecolor=magenta,      % color of file links
    urlcolor=cyan           % color of external links
}
\ifthenelse{\boolean{PrintVersion}}{   % for improved print quality, change some hyperref options
\hypersetup{    % override some previously defined hyperref options
%    colorlinks,%
    citecolor=black,%
    filecolor=black,%
    linkcolor=black,%
    urlcolor=black}
}{} % end of ifthenelse (no else)
\bibliography{bibfiles.d/.master,bibfiles.d/.psd,bibfiles.d/.Cook2012}


\begin{document}
fhjh  hjkhj
hohilkj
\end{document}
```

Comment: I changed the tag from `biblatex` to `bibtex` because it doesn't seem like you're using the former.. Feel free to revert if I've misunderstood

Comment: Your example compiles fine for me with no errors.

Comment: `\bibliography` tries to typeset the bibliography using `\thebibliography`. This is bound to fail. Maybe the template used to load package `biblatex`? In that case, it would work, but the tempalte would still be deprecated syntax. On the other hand, looking at that `hyperref` madness the template provides, i would put it in the bin,

Comment: @Troy - Deleting the `biblatex` tag may have been a bit premature: It could well be that the OP's template simply failed to provide the instruction `\usepackage[<various options>]{biblatex}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of two diagnoses:

- You simply failed to load the `biblatex` package. (A reason for contemplating this scenario is that your document doesn't include a `\bibliographystyle` instruction; such an instruction is required by BibTeX, but not by biblatex.) If `biblatex` isn't loaded, the `\bibliography` instruction *must not* be placed in the preamble. If it's simple failure of loading the `biblatex` package, do load it. You should also change the instruction

  ```
  \bibliography{bibfiles.d/.master,bibfiles.d/.psd,bibfiles.d/.Cook2012}
  ```

  to

  ```
  \addbibresource{bibfiles.d/.master.bib,bibfiles.d/.psd.bib,bibfiles.d/.Cook2012.bib}
  ```

  (Under biblatex, `\bibliography` is deprectated.) Note the addition of the `.bib` filename extensions. You're still planning on providing a few `\cite` instructions and a `\printbibliography` instruction too, right?
- You really do not intend to load the `biblatex` package. In that case, the `\bibliography` directive mustn't be placed in the preamble. Instead, it should be placed in the body of the document, in the location where the formatted bibliography should be placed. You will also need to provide a suitable `\bibliographystyle` directive, of course. And, you'll also be providing a few `\cite` instructions, right?

Incidentally, do the three `bib` files really all start with a `.` (dot)? This would make the "hidden" if they are located on a unix-like system.

Comment: Maybe worthy to note that no bib style was provided as well.

Comment: @Troy - Good observation! I'll add it to the body of the answer. :-)